# Need help collecting data from instagram for web scraping project

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, instagram

How would I go about gathering data from Instagram for a web scraping project, in particular I am interested in getting the caption as well as the number of likes

Answer (score 0):

1. check if there is an API that makes thinhs 100x easier
2. check the **terms of use** to make sure you are using it legaly
3. write the web scraper / api scaper
4. run it
5. process the data
6. be disappointed that it was not very interesting data